# Ruby on Rails - Query JOINS on object with several conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inner-join

RoR beginner here using rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3

Currently I am trying to show the availabilities of hotels that match the dates selected bt the user on two date_times.

```
    scope :by_availabilities, lambda { |first_day, last_day|
      joins(:rooms).
      joins('INNER JOIN availabilities ON rooms.id=availabilities.room_id').
      where(get_my_where(first_day, last_day)).
      group('hotels.id'<other fields>
    }

def self.get_my_where(first_day, last_day)
        difference = (last_day-first_day).to_i

        condition = ""


        if (difference==1)
          condition = "availabilities.day = '#{first_day}'"
          condition+=""
        else

            for i in 1..difference do
              if(i==difference)
                  condition +="(availabilities.day = '#{first_day}' AND availabilities.availability > 0)"
              else
                condition+="(availabilities.day = '#{first_day+i}' AND availabilities.availability > 0) AND "
              end

            end
        end
--other innerjoins--
```

The first_day is the in date and last_day is the out date, both are correclty declared and in a correct Date format.

I am passing the params correctly, the issue is I am only getting a correct search result if I select an in date of for eg today and an out date for tommorow. If I put more days in between, the search gives me no results at all, even though there are availabilities in the DB for those days.

Is this not the way to perform this? I can't put this search on the controller as there are  many INNER JOINS and it was getting "ugly", and all the searches by other filters worked correctly until I implemented this one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you instead just use the between operator directly in the scope that you've defined?  Something like this:

```
scope :by_availabilities, lambda { |first_day, last_day|
  scope = joins(:rooms).
          joins('INNER JOIN availabilities ON rooms.id=availabilities.room_id')
  (first_day..last_day).each { |day|
    scope = scope.where("availabilities.day = ?", day)
  }
  scope = scope.group('hotels.id'<other fields>)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner. This query works, however it does **not** have the desired behaviour as I want to return the **hotels that have availability in all those days**. This way, if there was an availability for just one day (and the search would be between day 1 and 5) that hotel would still be returned. What I am looking for is that the returned hotels have availabilities for all the selected days instead of just a couple of them. Thanks for your input though :)    Any more tips?

Comment: I see.  You could loop through the days and add a separate where clause for each of the days in the range.  These would be AND'd together.

Comment: I ended up trying what you said and it still didn't work for me. However I tried it with a simple `> and < and availability > 0` and it worked. Kind of strange as I though more complex operations were necessary. Although it is not optimized for performance, you pointed me in the right direction, therefore, I mark it as accepted. Thank you for you help.